# MVC Controller returns view with string type but not working with action result type

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, view, controller, routeconfig

Very basic issue but really frustrating. Wondering if someone can help.
This is my routeconfig:

> routes.MapRoute(
> name: "routeconfig1",
> url: "Test/welcome/{param1}/{param2}"
> routes.MapRoute(
> name: "routeconfig2",
> url: "Test/welcome2/{param1}/{param2}",

And this is my controller

> public class TestController : Controller
> {
> [HttpPost]
> public ActionResult welcome2(string param1, string param2)
> {
> return View("Default");
> }
> public string welcome(string param1, string param2)
> {
> return "Welcome " + param1 + ". Your Parameter is :" + param2;
> }
> }

Whenever I am trying to access MyWeb//Test/welcome?param1=ABCD&param2=1234 it works fine but  MyWeb//Test/welcome2?param1=ABCD&param2=1234 gives a 404 resource not found. Not even hitting the break point right at the beginning of welcome2 method declaration.